# `data` is not available in the `created` method of vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to access component data from within my `created()` method, but it seems unavailable (undefined). How can I access the data then?

```
<script>
import MainLayout from './MainLayout.vue'
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  components: { MainLayout },
  data: {
    loading: false,
    mytest: 123,
    table: {
      columns: [],
      data: [],
      total: 0,
    }
  },
  name: 'Entities',
  created: async function() {
    console.log(this.loading, this.table, this.mytest) // undefined, undefined, undefined

  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Docs says: Instead, a component’s data option must be a function, so that each instance can maintain an independent copy of the returned data object

Answer (score 1):

Use the method `mounted()` instead.

Comment: Still not working, everything is undefined. Strangely, what helped is returning data as a function, instead of as an object.

Comment: try with removing "async" : mounted: function() {console.log(...);}

Answer (score 1):

[vuejs official doc here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function) when you are using .vue single compoent then data should be a function it should return the data, if you use vue in normal html inside script tag then you can use data as object

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure why it worked, but turning `data` from an object into a function worked:

```
 data: function () {
    return {
      loading: false,
      mytest: 123,
      table: {
        columns: [],
        data: [],
        total: 0,
      }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is precaution of Vue.js - data property must be function -
so if using data property as object not a function that returning every new object, vue show you error message

Answer (score -1):

only when the component mounted could the data itself be accessed.

so if you want access `data` , you should wait util the component mounted, place the code into `mounted` lifecycle for example.